# Create unique buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery and am trying to create jQuery UI buttons dynamically and them to a list. I can create one list item but no more are appended after it. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#buttonList').append('<li><button>'+ username + '</button>')
       .button()
       .data('type', userType)
       .click(function(e) { alert($(this).data('type')); })
.append('<button>Edit</button></li>');

<div>
    <ul id="buttonList">    
    </ul>
</div>
```

This only creates one list item with two buttons (although the second button seems to be encased in the first one, but I can probably figure that issue out). How do I get it to create multiple list items with their own unique 'data' values (i.e. I can't do a `find()` on a particular button class and give it data values as all buttons would then have the same data)?

Comment: Is that the entire code or a snippet? Where do the username/userType variables come from?

Comment: Sorry, it's not the entire script as there are other parts of code and I'm not sure they're relevant. The variables exist and work fine, it's just that only one list item is ever created.

Comment: Well, you're only executing that code once. You'd need to loop over your list of usernames/usertypes and call the code that you have multiple times (once per username/usertype set). I don't know if you're trying to do that already since this is partial code.

Comment: This code resides in a function that gets called when another button is clicked. If I add an alert, it gets shown every time so I'm confident the code is being run every time the button is clicked.

Comment: This is probably more along the lines of what you were hoping to acheive.  Note how I started from the inside and worked out  http://jsfiddle.net/ZT7bp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to exchange the position of what you are appending and where you are appending to. This way, you retain the appended object, and should be able to work with it as a standard jQuery selector. From your code i commented out the `.button()` and the `.append()` lines, because i'm not sure what you want to do with them. Should you need help adding those lines, just drop a comment to my answer ;)

Oh, i almost forgot: i use var `i` to simulate different contents for `username` and `userType` data.

A JSFiddle for you is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cRjh9/1/

Example code (html part):

```
<div>
    <p id="addButton">add button</p>
    <ul id="buttonList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example code (js part):

```
var i = 0;

$('#addButton').on('click', function()
{

  $('<li><button class="itemButton">'+ 'username' + i + '</button></li>').appendTo('#buttonList')
  //.button()
  .find('.itemButton')
  .data('type', 'userType'+i)
  .click(function(e) { alert($(this).data('type')); 
                     })
  //.append('<button>Edit</button></li>')
  ;
  i++;

});
```

Comment: you are still misleading OP a bit too because events will be bound to the `<LI>` not the button

Comment: Added +1 to charlietfl comment because it's almost right, even considering the fact that a little `find()` in the chain could help returning the button instead of the `li` :)

Comment: Thanks, I can modify this code to actually return the button within the li but everything else seems to work nicely.

Comment: Code modified, so that if others have the same problem, they would see a correct code :)

Answer (score 2):

You need complete tags when you wrap any html in a method argument. You can't treat the DOM like a text editor and append a start tag, append some more tags and then append the end tag.

Anything insterted into the DOM has to be complete and valid html.

You are also not understanding the context of what is returned from `append()`. It is not the element(s) within the arguments it is the element collection you are appending to. You are calling `button()` on the whole `<UL>`.

I suggest you get a better understanding of jQuery before trying to chain so many methods together

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't want to chain but I wasn't sure how else to get the latest instance of the button that was created. If there is a way of avoiding chaining, I'd be happy to use that method.

Comment: @TryNCode I suggest you learn how to do all of this using strings of html first. It really isn't much code and the `data-` can be inline. Add your event handlers/plugins after insertion

Comment: He can use chaining. But, as charlietfl pointed out, the OP should understand what a jQuery function does and what it returns. In my answer, in fact, i keep almost everything of his code, but use the appended element as a selector for the chain :)

Comment: `$('#buttonList').append('<li><button>'+ username + '</button></li>')` seems to work fine for me, and multiple list items are added. The issue is trying to turn these buttons into jQuery-UI buttons.

Comment: @TryNCode at the end can simply do `$('#buttonList button').button()`

Answer (score 0):

Just a very simplistic approach that you can modify - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GfCMY/).

I haven't added the data attributes, nor the click function (I'm not really sure I like the
inline "click" functions - I generally do them in jQuery and try to figure out how to make
the code efficient. Probably not very rational, but I'm often so).

JS

```
var names = ['Washington', 'Adams', 'Jefferson', 'Lincoln', 'Roosevelt'];

for( r=0; r < names.length; r++ )
   {
    $('#buttonList').append('<li><button>'+ names[r] + '</button></li>');
    }

$('#buttonList').append('<li><button>Edit</button></li>');
```