# Creating Multiple Buttons - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects in Javascript. Without using any HTML, I need to add buttons for each object in the array. I know how to make buttons in Javascript like so:

```
//Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
```

But I'm not sure how to add one for each object in the array. Here is my array code for my array:

```
var items = [
{
name: "cake",
price:"7.00",
quantity:4
},

{
name:"fries",
price:"8.00",
quantity:3
},

{
name:"brownie",
price:"5.00",
quantity:2
},

{
name:"candy",
price:"9.00",
quantity: 12
},

]
```

I have more objects in my array but I have only added a few to minimize question and I want 'name' to be used as the label of the button. I know I will need to use a for loop but I'm stuck on what to write in the loop. I have tried searching about this question on Google but I wasn't able to find anything that showed how to do this in Javascript I only found other languages which I have not learned yet. Also I have already this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

I want to use the button as a like button. Each item will have a button, when that button is clicked on, the item will be displayed in a list. For ex: the user likes cake and fries so my "list" will say cake and fries. Each button can only be clicked once. This is similar to the concept of adding items to a shopping care but I'm using it for liked items.

Comment: Could you give an example of properties you want to use for each button created? I would recomment you research [**Document.createElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and how to loop through your array.

Comment: @NewToJS I have read this exact link already but I'm still stuck. Also I have updated my question to specify what I want to do for my button.

Comment: So the other properties other than the name are irrelevant to your current task but are shown in this example to let other know the object has more that one property?

Comment: @NewToJS Yes that is correct. I have only added them to let others know the object has more than one property. For my question I only want to display the name of item liked.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but I just joined today and don't have enough reputation to mark it as duplicate, so...
Stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886144/create-divs-from-array-elements :P
(Works if you are comfortable with jQuery.)

Comment: Might need to modify the code a little now that I think about it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question the link you posted is asking about divs I'm specifically asking about buttons.

Comment: @NewToJS Other properties are still needed but are irrelevant to the question I'm asking right now.

Comment: I have not learned jQuery yet GalaxyCat105

Comment: This is a duplicate question because the concept and method are the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create unique buttons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598347/create-unique-buttons-dynamically)

Comment: Since you haven't learnt jQuery yet, what you could d is just mix in jQuery with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a loop using the forEach() array method like:

```
const parentElement = document.querySelector('body'); // DOM location when buttons will be added
items.forEach(function(item) {
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerText = item.name;
  parentElement.appendChild(button); // to add new element to DOM
})
```

Comment: I tried this exact code and also tried changing it a bit but no buttons show up on the page.

Comment: once the button is created with createElement() you have to use something like, document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button) to add it to the page. (updated answer to show method)